# Show/Hide Div element with javascript button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I have a site using Google Maps Api which adds and saves markers. When a saved marker is clicked, it displays an info window which has a Button in it. When this button is clicked, I want it to display a hidden DIV element which contains a Table of the saved marker details.

The JS which contains the InfoWindow is:

```
var eventContent = $('<div class="event-info">' + '<h4 class="event-name">' + point.name + '</h4><hr>' +
        '<span><h5>Date: </h5>' +
        '<p class="event-date">' + point.edate + '</p></span>' +
        '<p class="event-description">'+ point.description +'</p>' + 
        '<button id="remove-event" name="remove-event" onclick="showDetails();" class="remove-event btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="View Event">View Event</button>'+
        '</div>');

    // Display Event details on marker click
    google.maps.event.addListener(event_markers[i], "click", function () {
        infowindow.setContent(eventContent[0]);
        infowindow.open(map, event_markers[i]);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        map.setZoom(10);
    });
```

The HTML DIV I want to display is:

```
<div class="event-details" id="event-details" style="display: none ">
        <h3>Event Details</h3>
        <table class="table"> 
            <tr>
                <th>Event Name: </th>
                <td> Bill Gates</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <th>Event Date: </th>
                <td> Bill Gates</td>
             </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove Event</button>
    </div>
```

I have tried this, among other similar ideas but no luck.:

```
function showDetails()
{
   if (document.getElementById("event-details").style.display == "none" ) {
       document.getElementById("event-details").style.display="";

   } else {
       document.getElementById("event-details").style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: you use getElementById, when your div has the class "event-details", not id. Change the attribute class to id

Comment: And please cache the `DOM` element as `DOM` scan is expensive, may be not in this case as it's not massive, but in general!

Comment: sorry, I meant to change that. I did try it id="event-details" and it didnt work

Answer (score 2):

Your elements do not have an `id` of "event-details" but a `class`. Try using `getElementsByClassName` instead:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("event-details")[0].style.display = "none"// returns multiple elements so you should select the first (0th) item.
```

Maybe a better solution would be to add an "id" to your html element:

```
<div id="event-details" class="event-details" style="display: none ">
```

This way, your `getElementById` method should catch the elements you want.

Comment: Why you are suggesting to use getElementsByClassName in 2015 when you can use querySelector and querySelectorAll?

Comment: I already had tried adding id="event-details" but it didnt work

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree with you @NikolayTalanov. I could explain how to `querySelector` works or I could give him a straight forward answer. It's pretty obvious what `getElementsByClassName` does.

Comment: @Stephen, I would open up your console to see if you have any javascript errors and then I would manually call `showDetails()` from your console to make sure that is setup properly. There are lots of things that could go wrong and debugging is the quickest way to find the culprit. In Chrome, you can open Developer Tools and then click on the "console" tab.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving the div an ID?

maybe why the "getElementById" isn't working.

then:

document.getElementById("eventDetails").style.display="none";

Comment: Yeah I already tried that, just forgot to include id="event-details" in the question..its amended now though

Comment: Have you debugged it? you might be getting the element, getting element by ID doesn't return the element as one would expect. so the ".style.display" isn't easily accessible

Answer (score 0):

FIXED.
My showDetails function had a syntax error, was missing a closing }

```
function showDetails()
{
   if (document.getElementById("event-details").style.display == "none" ) {
       document.getElementById("event-details").style.display="block";

   }
   else
   {
      document.getElementById("event-details").style.display="none";
    }
}
```

Comment: aha! Very nice you figured!

Answer (score 0):

Please use `querySelector` as below. Since you already have an id for the element you'd click on, like below:

```
<button id="remove-event" name="remove-event" class="remove-event btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="View Event">View Event</button>
```

You may remove the `onclick` inline event handler and do it the following way.

```
document.querySelector("#remove-event").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var elem = document.querySelector("#event-details");
    if (elem.style.display == "none") {
        elem.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        elem.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be try these-

1) Change the div id to other instead of having the class name

2) Here you are checking for 'none', but i think if you are not showing the div anywhere in your code prior calling this code, you can remove the if clause, since that div was already hidden and if clause wouldn't work if its already hidden.

```
if (document.getElementById("event-details").style.display == "none" ) {
       document.getElementById("event-details").style.display="";
   }
```

3) Try to use- instead of

```
 document.getElementById("event-details").style.display="";
```

to

```
document.getElementById("event-details").style.display=block;
```

or

```
document.getElementById("event-details").show();
```